# How can I show a new view from the UITableViewController contained my UIViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, view, properties

I have a `UITableViewController` within a `UIViewController`.  While this table viewcontroller was the only one involved, it was pushing views just fine when the user would tap a row.  However, ever since I moved it to be one of two contained within the `UIViewController`, the taps of rows suddenly do nothing.

I've [tried searching around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9119607/how-can-i-push-a-new-view-controller-from-a-button-within-a-subview-another-vie) and I'm not the first to run into this problem, but none of the answers fit my circumstances or the questions have no working answers.  That link was the closest I found, but I'm not using storyboards -- I'm using separate XIBs.

**So how do I push a new view from a viewcontroller within a viewcontroller?**

To recap:

1. Here is what I had, and it worked fine in taking users to a new screen!

   ```
   // Normal table behavior, as illustrated by [another question][2].

   - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
   didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

       SomeView *detailViewController = [[SomeView alloc] initWithNibName:@"SomeView" bundle:nil];

       // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
       [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
   }
   ```
2. Now I have the viewcontroller as a property in a view -- and the above code, which is in the file for the tableviewcontroller and not at the "main" view, doesn't cause a new screen to appear anymore!

---

Thanks for the comments!  Here's some code to clarify my scenario.

1. The controllers within a controller.  This is a file from a test project I've been using to test the concept out.  In this case, I have a tableview controller within a tableview controller.

   ```
   @interface SimpleTableViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

   // This is the controller within the controller
   @property IBOutlet SecondTableViewController *secondTableController;
   @property IBOutlet UITableView *secondTable;
   ```
2. My `SecondTableViewController` has this fun bit.

   ```
   - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {
       // Navigation logic may go here. Create and push another view controller.

       UIViewController *detailViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SimpleNonTableViewController" bundle:nil];
       // ...
       // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
       [manualViewControllerParent.navigationController  pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
   }
   ```

The view that the user interacts with is hooked up to `SimpleTableViewController`.  In this way, `SecondTableViewController` is "within" `SimpleTableViewController`.  Feel free to comment if you'd like more details!

---

I've put my test/concept project on github.  https://github.com/hyliandanny/TableViewCeption

Comment: Are you trying to push a viewcontroller that has already been pushed earlier?

Comment: What do you mean "within a UIViewController? Is it a child view controller?

Comment: @rooster117 Not in this case, no.  The screen that shows up is uniquely reached through this table, for now.

Comment: @rdelmar The tableviewcontroller is now a property within a view.  Previously, the view was just a tableviewcontroller.

Comment: That doesn't really make sense. How did you get the table view controller in the other controller? In code? If so, post that.

Comment: @Danny I think you mean "UITableView", not "tableviewcontroller" inside your controller, is that right?

Comment: No, I have a controller within a controller.  I shall post code to clarify, thanks for commenting asking for details!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a custom container controller to do what you want. It would be easiest if you used a storyboard, but you can do it in code with xibs as well. The outer controller should be a UIViewController, not a table view controller. You can do something like this (in the outer controller):

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    UIViewController *detailViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SimpleNonTableViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self addChildViewController:detailViewController];
    detailViewController.view.frame = set the frame to what you want;
    [self.view addSubview:detailViewController.view];
    [detailViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}
```

You should read up on Apple's documentation for custom container controllers.

Comment: Custom container controller, eh?  Good to know!  I'll check that out, thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: I hate to do this to future researchers, but I am marking this answer as "the" answer even though I solved it in another manner.  The reason behind this is that Custom Container Controllers are an iOS 5.0+ solution reflecting what I actually used: delegates and protocols.  By defining protocol methods that could be implemented by the "outer" viewcontroller, the "inner" viewcontroller ended up calling a method that the containing/outer viewcontroller handled.  From what I was reading about Custom Container Controllers, this is the same idea as what rdelmar implied.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to make sure:

- Your `UITableView` delegate is hooked up to your controller. Otherwise it wouldn't call `didSelectRow`. You can do this in xib or in viewDidLoad method.
- Your self.navigationController is not nil
- Your detailViewController is not nil

I also think that what you mean is you have `UITableView` inside your `UIViewController`. `UITableView` is only the view, whereas `UITableViewController` is a controller. You can't have a controller inside another controller.

Comment: Why can't I have a controller inside another controller?

Comment: Yes you can have a controller inside another controller, that's why I asked in my comment if it was a child view controller. But the way the OP is doing it is wrong.

Comment: Heh, I *am* the OP!  I'm fine with being told something is wrong and I'd love to understand *why* it is wrong.  What is the correct way to toggle between two tables on a single screen, for example?  That was my original problem being solved.  You sound pretty confident, so I'm excited to hear your knowledge!  Thanks again!

Comment: @Danny you're right, you can have a controller inside another. I think rdelmar's way is the way to go.